# Does Expertise double all of a skill's modifiers or just the ability bonus?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, rogue, bard

hi all I have a quick question, to get my +n in the skills column for proficient skills do i add the multiplier from the attributes list ie my charisma is +3 do i then add my proficiency bonus of +5 to get +8 in my skills list and then when I get expertise in a skill do I double the entire thing or just the base score of +3 then add the +5 bonus? sorry it's just very unclear in the PHB

Comment: A +5 proficiency bonus? What level are you playing at?

Comment: level, 13 rogue and yeah i mean modifier

Comment: As a general comment: don't start at level 13 if you don't yet know how proficiency works. You're going to be swamped by complexity. Low levels are there for a reason.